# Collecting output from multiple parallel processes

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

My bash-script extracts a certain subset of files from a collection of compressed tar-archives to stdout -- for reformatting and saving into a combined CSV.

```bash
(
    for file in /path/*.tar.bz2
    do
        tar -O -xf $file '*/little.csv'
    done
) | reformat | sort > combined.csv
```

The tar-files are large, and perceptible time is spent uncompressing them and extracting the multiple `little.csv` from each.

The server has many processing cores, so it's tempting to parallelize the extraction -- by adding the `&` after the `tar`-command and placing a `wait` inside the subscript.

I'm sorting the lines anyway, so I'm not worried about the order of extraction. But I *am* worried about the parallel processes garbling each other's lines... Is there a solution, perhaps?

I can only think of using temporary files to hold the extractions from each archive, but I'd like to avoid them too -- for other reasons...

Comment: GNU parallel might help: [running tasks in parallel as well writing to single file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600877/74329)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks, @Cyrus -- I didn't know about this tool. Unfortunately, it is not installed on these servers I have. But I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: DO you have `xargs` installed?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _nside the subscript_, but I think even if you get this to work, you have no guaranteed that in the combined output, the individual lines are left intact, or broken apart.

Comment: Add a line to your (r)syslog config and then use `logger` to write to the new file written by syslog.

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates one possible way to do what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob nullglob lastpipe

function extract_csv_from_tbz_list
{
    (( $# == 0 )) && return 0
    local -r tbzfiles=( "$@" )

    extract_csv_from_tbz_list "${tbzfiles[@]:0:${#tbzfiles[*]}-1}"  \
        |   {
                tar -O -xf "${tbzfiles[@]: -1}" '*/little.csv'  \
                    | IFS= read -r -d '' tar_output
                cat
                printf '%s' "$tar_output"
            }
}

tbzfiles=( /path/*.tar.bz2 )
(( ${#tbzfiles[*]} == 0 )) && exit 0

extract_csv_from_tbz_list "${tbzfiles[@]}" | reformat | sort > combined.csv
```

- The code uses a recursive function to construct a multi-stage pipeline.
- Each pipeline stage runs `tar` on one of the `.tar.bz2` files.
- To prevent `tar` processes being held up by `tar` processes in other pipeline stages, each stage runs its `tar` process and captures its output before doing I/O with other pipeline stages.
- Once a pipeline stage has run its `tar` process and collected its output it uses `cat` to pass the outputs of previous pipeline stages to the next stage and then uses `printf` to pass the output of the current stage to the next stage.  This ensures that the outputs of `tar` processes don't get mixed.
- Since the code creates multiple processes, and an anonymous pipe, for each `.tar.bz2` file, it will fail due to exceeding system resource limits if the number of files is large.  I guess it should be OK up to 100 files on a modern system, but it would need to be modified if the real number is much more than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll need to test it, of course... I wonder, if the resource-consumption can be reduced by allowing complete lines through -- without waiting for the rest of the `tar_output`.